# Abs Function not providing required values

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have been trying this code to match a float value with another float value using the abs function.Here is the code:

```
float li=0;
float d=2;
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
   li=li+0.1125;
   Serial.println(li);
   if(abs(li-d)<0.2)
    {
      Serial.println('h');
      exit(0);
    }

}
```

I want the li value to reach nearest to the d value.The difference between the values should be less than 0.2.If true,then the if statement should execute.But, this is the output which I am getting:

```
0.11
0.22
0.34
0.45
0.56
0.68
0.79
```

The if statement exits after 0.79.Help!!! I am new to Arduino.

Comment: Check the difference between 'abs' and 'fabs'.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino Serial object uses interrupts to send data via the UART.

This helps to keep the time spent in the 'println' function as low as possible.

Basically, the Serial object does not send all the data sent to the 'println' function before returning control to the 'loop' function.
Because of this, when you run your code, the serial transmit buffer fills up.

So when your code actually enters the if condition, some data from the serial buffer has not reached your serial monitor.

The 'exit' function suspends all activity of the Arduino. So if there is any data in the Serial object's transmit buffer, it is not transmitted.

In your code, the abs function is doing its job correctly. It's just that some of the numbers on the Serial object's buffer are not being transmitted, and you feel something is wrong. You will need to empty the Serial objects transmit buffer before calling the 'exit' function to see the results you want.

Make the following changes to the if condition, and you will have all the data correctly printed before the application runs the exit function.

```
if(abs(li-d)<0.2)
{
  Serial.println('h');
  Serial.flush();
  exit(0);
}
```

I hope this helps.